# How can I know if the relayProtocol used by my local relay candidate is tcp or udp?

Tags: webrtc, turn

Whether it's js for browser or android sdk, I can't seem to find an exact property indicating whether the candidate is connecting to turn via udp or tcp.

Answer (score 1):

Open `about://webrtc-internals/` and open the tab for your connection. Then under `local-candidate` check the protocol, e.g.:

```
local-candidate (candidateType=relay, relayProtocol=udp, id=I3MLk9CWG)
  Statistics I3MLk9CWG
  timestamp 6/7/2023, 7:52:44 AM
  transportId   Tvideo01
  isRemote  false
  networkType   unknown
  ip    54.184.68.133
  address   54.184.68.133
  port  34581
  protocol  udp
  relayProtocol udp   // <---
  candidateType relay
  priority  33562623
  url   turn:transitiverobotics.com:3478?transport=udp
  foundation    4225971487
  usernameFragment  TGiw
  vpn*  false
  networkAdapterType*   any
```

**Updated**: showing a case with `relayProtocol` present

---

To get programmatic access to this, use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/getStats.

Comment: thank you very much, but... I just want to use API to get it...

Comment: you can do that, too. I'll add to the answer.

Comment: protocol is *not* the protocol used for the connection between the client and the TURN server but the protocol of the relayed socket which will always be "udp" for WebRTC.
What you are looking for is `relayProtocol` as described [here](https://w3c.github.io/webrtc-stats/#dom-rtcicecandidatestats-relayprotocol)

Comment: Thanks @PhilippHancke, I've updated the example to show the stats of a local candidate with a `relayProtocol` field present (by forcing a relay connection).